# Update total relation counter in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Stupid question, but i can't find any answer.

I need to execute a query like this:

```
$em
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('AppBundle:Contest\Member', 'm')
    ->innerJoin('m.votes', 'v')
    ->set('m.total_votes', 'COUNT(v.id)')
    ->where('m.id = :member')
    ->setParameter('member', $member->id())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```

or through `DQL`

```
UPDATE
    AppBundle:Contest\Member AS m
INNER JOIN
    m.votes v
SET
    m.total_votes = COUNT(v.id)
WHERE
    m.id = :member
```

Doctrine categorically refuse to execut query.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
$total = $em
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Contest\Member\Vote')
    ->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('COUNT(v.id)')
    ->where('v.member = :member')
    ->setParameter('member', $member->getId())
    ->getDQL()
;

$em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('AppBundle:Contest\Member', 'm')
    ->set('m.total_votes', '('.$total.')')
    ->where('m.id = :member')
    ->setParameter('member', $member->getId())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```